# How to add a column in a csv file to count the amount of classes according to the date

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to make a column in a csv file in colab to count the number of classes depending on the date of a timestamp column

timestamp / class_id
2021-09-27 06:00:00 / A
2021-09-27 03:00:00 / A
2021-09-27 01:00:00 / A
2021-09-27 08:29:00 / C
2021-05-23 08:08:49 / B
2021-05-23 03:21:49 / B
2021-05-23 01:22:11 / C

Expected result:
count / timestamp / class_id
1 / 2021-09-27 06:00:00 / A
2 / 2021-09-27 03:00:00 / A
3 / 2021-09-27 01:00:00 / A
1 / 2021-09-27 08:29:00 / C
1 / 2021-05-23 08:08:49 / B
2 / 2021-05-23 03:21:49 / B
1 / 2021-05-23 01:22:11 / C

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/Colab_Notebooks/classproject/classdata.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'], index_col='timestamp')
class_id = data['class_id']

count = 0
data['count'] = count
index = -1
for row in data:
  index = index + 1
  if class_id[index] == class_id[index-1]:
    data['count'] = count + 1
  elif count == 0: 
    data['count'] = count + 1
  else:
    data['count'] = 1

data.head()
```

this is my code so far but this is the output
timestamp / class_id / count
2021-09-27 06:00:00 / A / 1
2021-09-27 03:00:00 / A / 1
2021-09-27 01:00:00 / A / 1
2021-09-27 08:29:00 / C / 1
2021-05-23 08:08:49 / B / 1
2021-05-23 03:21:49 / B / 1
2021-05-23 01:22:11 / C / 1

current error:
[image: error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop here. Try a vectorized way:

```
# Method 1: OR logic
class_id = df['class_id']
timestamp = df.index.to_series()
m1 = class_id.ne(class_id.shift())
m2 = timestamp.dt.date.ne(timestamp.dt.date.shift())
df['count'] = df.groupby((m1 | m2).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1).values

# Method 2: NOT AND logic
class_id = df['class_id']
timestamp = df.index.to_series()
m1 = class_id.eq(class_id.shift())
m2 = timestamp.dt.date.eq(timestamp.dt.date.shift())
df['count'] = df.groupby((~(m1 & m2)).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1).values
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                    class_id  count
timestamp                          
2021-09-27 06:00:00        A      1
2021-09-27 03:00:00        A      2
2021-09-27 01:00:00        A      3
2021-09-27 08:29:00        C      1
2021-05-23 08:08:49        B      1
2021-05-23 03:21:49        B      2
2021-05-23 01:22:11        C      1
```

Comment: hey so I tried using this to train an algorithm to predict number of classes in the future but I realised that it doesn't work because the algorithm does not use the total classes of each day to predict is there a way for me to count the number of classes per date?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: sorry it's okay! I've gotten the answer on another question already

Answer (score 2):

fixed it! A combination of both edits, I added a visit date condition in the if else statement thanks for the help!

```
data = pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/Colab_Notebooks/classproject/classdata.csv', parse_dates=['timestamp'], index_col='timestamp')
class_id = data['class_id']
timestamp = data.index.date

count = 0
data['count'] = [1 for _ in range(len(data))]
index = 1
for row in range(1, len(data)):
  if class_id[index] == class_id[index - 1] and timestamp[index] == timestamp[index-1]:
    # set the count for this index to +1 of the last index
    data['count'][index] = data['count'][index - 1] + 1
    #data count column = data count column previous count + 1
  # (otherwise do nothing and leave it at 1)

  # move on to next index
  index += 1

data.head(10)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from typing import Generator
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd


def _get_df() -> pd.DataFrame:
    start = dt.datetime(2021, 5, 23, 7, 0)
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "stamp": [start + dt.timedelta(hours=-i) for i in range(7)],
            "class_id": list("AAACBBC"),
        }
    )
    df["count"] = list(_get_counts(df.class_id))
    return df


def _get_counts(s: pd.Series) -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    prev = None
    count = 1
    for val in s:
        if val == prev:
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 1
        yield count
        prev = val


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(_get_df())
```

output:

```
                stamp class_id  count
0 2021-05-23 07:00:00        A      1
1 2021-05-23 06:00:00        A      2
2 2021-05-23 05:00:00        A      3
3 2021-05-23 04:00:00        C      1
4 2021-05-23 03:00:00        B      1
5 2021-05-23 02:00:00        B      2
6 2021-05-23 01:00:00        C      1
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is close to working! The problem is that you're setting `data["count"] = count` where `count` is just an integer, not an *array* of integers, so every value will always be the same.

So instead you can initially set all of the counts to 1 with an array, and then change each count based on the previous one by indexing into it with `data["count"][i]`. Here's an example snippet you can put into your code.

```
# start by setting all to one
data['count'] = [1 for _ in range(len(data))]

# loop over the rows (skipping the first)
for index in range(1, len(data)):
    # if the class is the same as the previous one
    if class_id[index] == class_id[index - 1]:
        # set the count for this index to +1 of the last index
        data.loc[index, 'count'] = data.loc[index - 1, 'count'] + 1

  # (otherwise do nothing and leave it at 1)
```

Comment: thank you! it works but after the first date the count stops counting and becomes one again for some reason

Comment: is there a fix to the above comment?

Comment: Sorry about that, the iterator was incorrect so the loop finished early, my updated answer should work

Comment: now there is a new error, I have put it in the post above