# dropping specific rows through datetime column by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I am trying to drop specific rows of dates where there are only one class, so far there are no errors shown during the isolating of single class dates but the deletion part is where I'm having troubles, to explain briefly, I isolated the dates where there are only one class into a to_drop_dates list, I then attempted to go through the dataframe to find said dates to drop them but when I try to find other dates that should not have been deleted, it came up empty

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/Colab_Notebooks/classproject/classdata.csv', parse_dates=['visit_date'], index_col='visit_date')
doctor_id = data['doctor_id']
visit_date = data.index.date

count = 0
data['count'] = [1 for _ in range(len(data))]
index = 1
for row in range(1, len(data)):
  if doctor_id[index] == class_id[index - 1] and timestamp[index] == timestamp[index-1]:
    # set the count for this index to +1 of the last index
    data['count'][index] = data['count'][index - 1] + 1
    #data count column = data count column previous count + 1
  # (otherwise do nothing and leave it at 1)

  # move on to next index
  index += 1

data.head(10)

import numpy as np

unique_dates, unique_date_count = np.unique(visit_date, return_counts=True)
unique_date_count[:3]

to_drop_dates = []
unique_dates_index = 0


for row in unique_dates:
  for row in unique_date_count:
    while unique_dates_index < len(unique_dates):
      if unique_date_count[unique_dates_index] == 1:
        to_drop_dates.append(unique_dates[unique_dates_index])
      unique_dates_index += 1


to_drop_dates[:9]
```

The output of to_drop_dates:

```
[datetime.date(2023, 4, 2),
 datetime.date(2023, 6, 12),
 datetime.date(2023, 6, 15),
 datetime.date(2023, 6, 16),
 datetime.date(2023, 9, 1),
 datetime.date(2023, 9, 17)]
```

```
data_index = 0
dropdates_index = 0
for row in visit_date:
  while data_index < len(visit_date):
    for row in to_drop_dates:
      while dropdates_index < len(to_drop_dates):
        if to_drop_dates[dropdates_index] == visit_date[data_index]:
          data.drop(index = visit_date)
        dropdates_index += 1
    data_index += 1

data['Date'] = data.index.date
df2 = data[(data['Date'] == "2021-09-28")]
print("Filter rows by dates:\n",df2)
```

Output:

```
Filter rows by dates:
 Empty DataFrame
Columns: [queue_id, doctor_id, visit_purpose, count, Date]
Index: []
```

I tried doing this fix but now it messed up my counting of the dates from here [part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77817417/how-to-add-a-column-in-a-csv-file-to-count-the-amount-of-classes-according-to-th)

```
ndates = dict(data.index.value_counts())
keep_dates = [k for (k,v) in ndates.items() if v > 1]
udf = data.loc[data.index.isin(keep_dates)]

udf
```

output:
count / date / class
3 / 2020-10-19 / A
5 / 2020-10-19 / A
1 / 2023-10-20 / A
1 / 2023-10-20 / A
1 / 2023-10-09 / A
2 / 2023-10-09 / B
1 / 2023-08-07 / A
1 / 2023-08-07 / B
3 / 2023-08-07 / A
1 / 2023-08-07 / B
1 / 2023-02-03 / A
1 / 2023-02-03 / B

supposed output:

count / timestamp / class_id
1 / 2021-09-27 06:00:00 / A
2 / 2021-09-27 03:00:00 / A
3 / 2021-09-27 01:00:00 / A
1 / 2021-09-27 08:29:00 / C
1 / 2021-05-23 08:08:49 / B
2 / 2021-05-23 03:21:49 / B
1 / 2021-05-23 01:22:11 / C

I also tried the other fix also same problem, may have to take into account the counting column

```
out = data[data.groupby(data.index.date).transform('size').gt(1)]
```

date / count / class
2021-09-28 / 1 / C
2021-09-27 / 1 / A
2021-09-27 / 2 / A
2021-09-27 / 3 / A
2021-09-27 / 4 / A
2021-02-01 / 1 / A
2021-02-02 / 1 / B
2021-02-01 / 1 / A
2021-09-28 / 1 / C
2021-09-28 / 2 / C

Comment: Are you trying to keep duplicated dates and delete unique dates?

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 yes

Comment: @Sonny. You have to share some input data for better understanding your code, please.

Comment: @Corralien you can see the data here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77817417/how-to-add-a-column-in-a-csv-file-to-count-the-amount-of-classes-according-to-th

Comment: @Corralien it's okay! I am trying to separate the unique dates from the input data, those dates with only one class during that day I want to delete them from the input data if that makes sense! for example, I want to keep 2021-09-27 as it has 4 classes that day but 2021-09-26 has only one class and I want to delete that only leaving the 2021-09-27 in the data

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you at the moment because I don't understand why my answer isn't working. When you have a correct input with the expected result, I'm sure I have the solution. Is the "count" column actually relevant to solving your problem? I follow your question so if you update your post I will be notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby_transform` to remove unique dates:

```
out = data[data.groupby(data.index.date).transform('size').gt(1)]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                     col1
2024-01-13 16:00:00     2
2024-01-16 18:00:00     5
2024-01-16 06:00:00     7
2024-01-13 18:00:00     8
```

Input:

```
>>> data
                     col1
2024-01-14 17:00:00     0
2024-01-11 06:00:00     1
2024-01-13 16:00:00     2  # 2 instances of 2024-01-13
2024-01-09 04:00:00     3
2024-01-17 07:00:00     4
2024-01-16 18:00:00     5  # 2 instances of 2024-01-16
2024-01-18 23:00:00     6
2024-01-16 06:00:00     7  # 2 instances of 2024-01-16
2024-01-13 18:00:00     8  # 2 instances of 2024-01-13
2024-01-07 22:00:00     9
```

Comment: I've tried your code but it seems that there is another problem I've edited the question to include the code

Answer (score 0):

First, find the count of unique values in the index using [pandas.Index.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.value_counts.html) and then convert it to a dictionary.

```
ndates = dict(data.index.value_counts())
```

Second, find the duplicate dates by finding keys (dates) with values (count occurence) more than 1.

```
keep_dates = [k for (k,v) in ndates.items() if v > 1]
```

Finally, filter the index with duplicate dates using [pandas.Index.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html).

```
data.loc[data.index.isin(keep_dates)]
```

Comment: there is a type error on the second line (keep_dates = [k...] TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable Timestamp object

Comment: @Sonny Ahh, sorry. I forgot to use `items()` method to return the key-value pairs of the dictionary. I think it's fixed now.

Comment: I have a column with a count column that counts the total number of dates that occurs in the csv file after adding this code it seems to have messed up that column, above I added the code for the column and the output